# How to stop ESC from closing Terminals on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, wsl2

WSL and also PowerShell and CMD Windows get closed on <kbd>ESC</kbd> Key somehow.
At least in WSL, <kbd>ESC</kbd> is not even passed into the shell. If in `vi` insert mode I try to exit to normal mode, the WSL Window closes instead...

What causes that behaviour and how can it be changed?

Comment: What you describe does not happen here:  Terminal or CMD, Windows 10 or 11. You must EXIT .   ESC does not quit.  Try DISM / SFC and see if that helps.  .... (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: Does it happen when booting in Safe mode?

Answer (score -1):

I have this AutoHotkey Tool [a2](https://github.com/ewerybody/a2), that i started to suspect as the Cause.
Quitting it, the Problem was gone immediately.

But i could not trigger the issue again. I guess a script within a2 went rogue for some reason.
So for now i can't tell exactly what the problem was.